# My Aspect has two Pointcuts,But there's not work?

Tags: spring-boot, aspect, pointcuts

All right, I have a problem ,This is my logs Aspect. It's true that he has two Pointcuts .But every time I request the interface, I repeat 4 times.
spring boot version 1.5.10.RELEASE
github:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12570

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first then read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to form your question better.

Comment: Are you serious? This is your problem description? "I have a problem." And this is your subject? "My aspect has 2 pointcuts but does not work." And no code whatsoever. You got to be kidding us.

Comment: I've said that, I'm wrong,I find the wrong point, my error caused by the multiple target method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the wrong point, my error caused by the multiple target method